# Immutable, "finite" data type with __new__

Tags: python-3.x

first off I just want to say that this is my first time asking a question on this website... I searched if a similar question had already been asked and came up empty, but if there is indeed a duplicate somewhere, I'm sorry for wasting your time.

Here's my problem: I'm writing a class that represents the different pitches that can be played on a piano and is essentially a wrapper around an int in a certain range. Because objects of this type are encapsulated by just about every other object in my program (e.g. I need a pitch inside every note object, key signature object, etc.) and there is only a very limited amount of pitches that are playable on a piano (88 to be exact), I would like objects representing the same pitch to be the same object (at least that seems more elegant and efficient to me).

My current implementation goes something like this:

```
class Pitch:

    __pitches = dict()

    def __new__(cls, value: int):
        if value in cls.__pitches:
            return cls.__pitches[value]
        self = super().__new__(cls)
        self.__pitch = value
        cls.__pitches[value] = self
        return self
```

However upon calling e.g. `Pitch(60)` I get the error that `__init__` takes 0 positional arguments, not 1. When I include a

```
def __init__(self, value: int):
    pass
```

everything works beautifully... Except that I then get a warning about `__init__` not using the parameter `value`. This leads me to believe that there must be some better, more valid, official way of achieving what I want to achieve. So is there?

I'm using Python 3.8.0 and my IDE is PyCharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to take the hybrid approach: use `__new__` *only* for determining whether an existing instance should be used and to manage the dictionary, and use `__init__` to actually initialise the new instance:

```
class Pitch:
    __pitches = dict()

    def __new__(cls, value: int):
        if value not in cls.__pitches:
            cls.__pitches[value] = super().__new__(cls)
        return cls.__pitches[value]
        
    def __init__(self, value: int):
        self.__pitch = value

a4 = Pitch(440)
a5 = Pitch(880)
dupe = Pitch(440)

print(a4 == a5, a4 == dupe)  # False True
```